# Diazo is only for plone4?

Tags: plone, xdv, diazo

I used xdv for plone 3.x sites, Diazo for plone 4 sites.
Diazo is the best for many reasons but I don't understand if it's possible to use it with a plone3.x site. Maybe I need to use Diazo only in WSGI mode... right?

Thank's
Vito

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason you can't use Diazo in Plone 3, but the plone.app.theming integration relies on some Plone 4-specific code.

It wouldn't be too hard to make it work in Plone 3, using collective.xdv as a reference point, but someone would need to make the backporting effort.

The WSGI approach would work, but getting Plone 3 to run in a WSGI stack is fairly tricky, and you probably want to avoid a separate proxy process.

Another option would be to use the Diazo standalone proxy (see diazo.org) for development, and then use diazocompiler to generate an XSL and deploy that into nginx/Apache for production. A bit more fiddly, but should work unless you rely on Plone-specific expressions/variables in your rules file.

Martin

Comment: Using Diazo standalone: Is this the best way also for the edit mode? How manage the cache using this approach? Thank you